# RedirectStandardInput crashes program

Tags: c#

the following code is to open a console application (which uses pdcurses for output, nothing special):

```
  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "some.exe";
  myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
  myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  myProcess.Start();
```

The Problem is that it opens the designated window but directly closes it (it's barely visible). Starting the program without RedirectStandardInput works. The problem is that it does not throw an exception nor any error-message. What is wrong with my code? How can I write input to the program? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Is some.exe a console program?

You could try starting cmd.exe with the /K switch and pass your some.exe as the argument to it.

Comment: This does not work either, same error. As I said, it's a console program written in Cpp using dpcurses.